# Issues with query tool in pgAdmin 4

Tags: pgadmin-4

I've been using pgAdmin III for about three years, but we're now being forced over to pgAdmin 4 on our new PCs. I'm missing some of the functionality, and I haven't been able to find any answers to these questions in the documentation on the query tool, so I'm guessing maybe the things I want to do just aren't possible.

1) Can I open a new query tool instance in its own window, or am I stuck with tabs in the main pdAgmin window?

2) In pgAdmin III, you could easily switch between databases from a dropdown box at the top of the query window. I don't see any way to do that in the query tool tabs. Is the only way to open another instance in the correct database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes, you can open Query tool in a separate window

[image]

After opening a tab, you can click and drag the tab out of the pgAdmin window to create its own window.

*Update*: The location of this setting has changed. Currently it can be found under `Browser/Tab Settings`:

[image: preferences updated]

2. Unfortunately, At a moment there is no way to change the database from Query tool window, each time you have open new query tool instance from required database but it's in TODO feature list, We will hope to get it soon :)
   Ref: [Link](https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/2553)